# yum remove *wildcard* except some packages that also matched the wildcard?

Tags: centos, yum

I'm trying to remove a bunch of packages that have 'abc' in it. However, I don't want to remove 'abc-def'. How can I accomplish this?

For example, how to remove every packages that have 'php' in it, except 'php-common'?

I tried adding `--exclude` to the command, but it doesn't work as expected - 'php-common' was still in the deletation list.

```
# yum --exclude=php-common remove *php*
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.el7_1 will be erased
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.el7_1 will be erased
---> Package php-fpm.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.el7_1 will be erased
---> Package php-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.4.16-3.el7 will be erased
---> Package php-mysqlnd.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.el7_1 will be erased
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.el7_1 will be erased
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
```

`yum remove *php* !php-common`,`--exclude=php-common*` and `--exclude=php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.16-36.el7_1` doesn't work either.

I'm asking this because I have a huge package (~1.5 GB) that I still need and don't want to re-download it because my internet is slow.

OS: CentOS 7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply prefix the package name that you want to keep with `-`.  You need to add `--` before the list of packages to ensure that the name of the package is not treated like an option:

```
yum remove *php* -- -php-common
```

From the man page (under the install option):

> If the name starts with a - character, then a search is done within
>   the transaction and any matches are removed.

Comment: Neat, but I needed to reverse it to `yum remove *php* -- -php-common`.

Answer (score 5):

`--exclude` will exclude a package from the repositories, as it wasn't available to install, but it doesn't act on installed packages.

One way to *really* protect your package from deinstallation is to put its name into `protected_packages` in `/etc/yum.conf`, but then `yum` wouldn't process a wildcard that also matches that package.

One solution:

With your specific example `php-common`, this will not really work as the dependency resolver will interfere, but if dependencies are not a problem, you can try the following:

```
yum erase `yum list installed | cut -d " " -f 1  | grep php | grep -v php-common `
```

The subcommand will generate a list of installed packages, cut it to the first column, reduce it to packages containing `php` in the name and then eliminates `php-common` from the list.

Answer (score 1):

╮(╯_╰)╭
I wrote a python to resolve this problem yesterday.
I hope it is useful for you and who was troubled about this problem.
: - )

I noted down the development process on my blog
http://blog.j3l11234.com/2016/11/23/yum-remove-with-exclude/

here is the usage:

```
# ./remove.py -e *php* -x php-common
analyzing exclude packages and their dependencies ...

analyzing packages which will be removed...

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:7.0.12-2.el7.remi will be erased
---> Package php-fpm.x86_64 0:7.0.12-2.el7.remi will be erased
---> Package php-gd.x86_64 0:7.0.12-2.el7.remi will be erased
---> Package php-mbstring.x86_64 0:7.0.12-2.el7.remi will be erased
---> Package php-mysqlnd.x86_64 0:7.0.12-2.el7.remi will be erased
---> Package php-opcache.x86_64 0:7.0.12-2.el7.remi will be erased
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:7.0.12-2.el7.remi will be erased
---> Package php-xml.x86_64 0:7.0.12-2.el7.remi will be erased
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

==============================================================================================================
 Package            Arch         Version                  Repository                                     Size
==============================================================================================================
Removing:
 php-cli            x86_64       7.0.12-2.el7.remi        @/php-cli-7.0.12-2.el7.remi.x86_64             12 M
 php-fpm            x86_64       7.0.12-2.el7.remi        @/php-fpm-7.0.12-2.el7.remi.x86_64            4.1 M
 php-gd             x86_64       7.0.12-2.el7.remi        @/php-gd-7.0.12-2.el7.remi.x86_64             203 k
 php-mbstring       x86_64       7.0.12-2.el7.remi        @/php-mbstring-7.0.12-2.el7.remi.x86_64       2.8 M
 php-mysqlnd        x86_64       7.0.12-2.el7.remi        @/php-mysqlnd-7.0.12-2.el7.remi.x86_64        868 k
 php-opcache        x86_64       7.0.12-2.el7.remi        @/php-opcache-7.0.12-2.el7.remi.x86_64        396 k
 php-pdo            x86_64       7.0.12-2.el7.remi        @/php-pdo-7.0.12-2.el7.remi.x86_64            381 k
 php-xml            x86_64       7.0.12-2.el7.remi        @/php-xml-7.0.12-2.el7.remi.x86_64            854 k

Transaction Summary
==============================================================================================================
Remove  8 Packages

Installed size: 22 M
Is this ok [y/N]:
```

[download link](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=26787&d=1479875656)